# How to make the child div's height higher the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I've seen the way to set this element's width to the width of another element, but I haven't seen the way to do this for the height.
Could someone explain how to do this with only the height?

[image: Example]

Comment: `.parent .child {height: 105%;}`?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this yourself? Unless we know what you've attempted, we can't help you correct whatever the problem may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *From next time, please **include** what you have attempted. StackOverflow is **not** a free coding service.*

You need to use `position`ing here:

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 100px; border: 2px solid #333; text-align: center; height: 150px;}
.parent .child {position: absolute; border: 2px solid #999; height: 250px; top: -50px; left: -2px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent Div
  <div class="child">Child Div</div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

I would like to give full credits for [Joseph-Marikle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph-marikle) for attempting something awesome like this, using **relative** values.

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
}
.parent {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 15vw auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  top: -50%;
  height: 200%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I would really wanna appreciate the colour combinations. `:)`

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: This is pretty close to how I would answer this too, but I'm curious, is there a particular reason you chose to use static values for height and top?  Why not go for something like `height:200%;top:-50%;`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I didn't think of it mate. Do you want me to update? `:)`

Comment: And I don't know why this answer was downvoted. Funny guys!

Comment: You can feel free to.  This was the fiddle I was playing with (not exactly minimal though.  Got a little carried away with styles and whatnot): https://jsfiddle.net/f8aac4jg/.  You can incorporate a part two in your answer that shows the same method using relative values, but it's up to you.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's awesome! `:)`

Comment: @JosephMarikle Added your version and gave due credits. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have finished it the way you explained it.

Comment: lol didn't need credit, but thanks for adding it.  It's good to have multiple options for a given solution.  Thanks for adding it to your answer.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Na... Feeling guilty to show off, because it is too nice to steal it from you. :)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `position`ing your elements you can simply do this but making the child element have more `height`. Negative `margin` is an accepted value, make sure your `overflow` on the `parent` is `visible` (this is the [default value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2ko5gmef/2/)**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 75px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.parent {
  overflow: visible;
}

.child {
  border-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly put the `overflow: visible`, coz it is the default. Nice awesome attempt. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar this is true, but I figured I would explicitly tell the OP to make sure, so he doesn't accidentally set it to `hidden` - but you are 100% correct that it is the default value

Comment: Awesome answer anyways, voted up! :) Way to go.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I figured an alternative to `position` method might be helpful, so many people forget negative `margin` is acceptable (although I would probably solve the issue personally with `position` as you've done:)

Comment: Great buddy. Looks nice.